# Is there any way to add a rectangle/colorbar into the Frame?

Tags: python, matplotlib, opencv

I would like to add color bar with `jet` color map into my frame exactly like the picture below. tried to look over the web but did not find anything.

any ideas?

[image]

Comment: [Does this suffice](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axes_grid1/demo_colorbar_with_inset_locator.html)?

Comment: Except suggest you use the axes inset_axes rather than the one from the toolbox

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

1. create a transparent heatmap with correct alpha values
2. use `plt.contourf` to add the heatmap on the image
3. use [`inset_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/api/inset_locator_api.html#mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes) to position the colorbar

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes


def transparent_cmap(cmap, N=255):
    fix_cmap = cmap
    fix_cmap._init()
    fix_cmap._lut[:,-1] = np.linspace(0, 0.8, N+4)
    return fix_cmap

fix_cmap = transparent_cmap(plt.cm.Reds)
im = Image.open('test.jpg')
w, h = im.size
y, x = np.mgrid[0:h, 0:w]
heat = np.zeros((h,w))
heat[500:550,500:550] = np.random.random((50,50))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.imshow(im)
plt.contourf(x, y, heat, 15, cmap=fix_cmap)
cbaxes = inset_axes(ax, width="3%", height="30%", loc=1)
plt.colorbar(cax=cbaxes)
plt.show()
```

This will give:

[image]

Comment: I need the color bar you have plotted aside ,inside the picture with the dog, shrinked but with the same values

Comment: @AmitayTsinis see my edit. You should play with the parameter to get the desired plot but this is the main idea

Comment: @ David S see my desired result attached above, I need the color bar to act as a legend ,it need it to be independent to the picture, I already know the values of the color bar. I see in your code the color bar is dependent on the small rectangle you have drawn